# Do I require office 2007 installed in server, so that I can import excel 2007 into SQL using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql, excel

I have a client server where they don't have office 2007 installed.
They need a feature where they can import the contents of excel into their SQL.

I have used oledbconnection to import.
The feature works without any problem on my laptop(Office 2007 installed) for the same excel sheet.

So please tell me whether it is necessary to install office 2007 into server?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

you need Office [2007 Microsoft Office system Primary Interop Assemblies (PIA)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=18346) to install on to the server Or either use [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the issue of OLEDB.ACE.12.0 by setting "32bit application" to true in "advanced settings" of site in IIS on a 64 bit server machine.

Regards.
B.Srikanth